# Extracting caption from alt attribute and inserting into a div

Tags: jquery, extract, alt-attribute

I am using the rather lovely jQuery slideviewer 1.1 plugin on a site at the moment, but would like to extract the alt attribute from images displayed and insert them into a div at the appropriate time.

The current code for the plugin is shown below for reference:

```
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery("div.svw").prepend("<img src='/template/theme/designdistillery/img/bg-portfolio-loading.gif' class='ldrgif' alt='loading...'/ >"); 
});
var j = 0;
var quantofamo = 0;
jQuery.fn.slideView = function(settings) {
    settings = jQuery.extend({
    easeFunc: "easeInOutExpo",
    easeTime: 750,
    toolTip: false
    }, settings);
    return this.each(function(){
        var container = jQuery(this);
        container.find("img.ldrgif").remove(); // removes the preloader gif
        container.removeClass("svw").addClass("stripViewer");       
        var pictWidth = container.find("img").width();
        var pictHeight = container.find("img").height();
        var pictEls = container.find("li").size();
        var stripViewerWidth = pictWidth*pictEls;
        container.find("ul").css("width" , stripViewerWidth); //assegnamo la larghezza alla lista UL    
        container.css("width" , pictWidth);
        container.css("height" , pictHeight);
        container.each(function(i) {

            jQuery(this).after("<div class='stripTransmitter' id='stripTransmitter" + (j) + "'><ul><\/ul><\/div>");
            jQuery(this).find("li").each(function(n) {
                        jQuery("div#stripTransmitter" + j + " ul").append("<li><a title='" + jQuery(this).find("img").attr("alt") + "' href='#'>"+(n+1)+"<\/a><\/li>");                                             
                });
            jQuery("div#stripTransmitter" + j + " a").each(function(z) {
                jQuery(this).bind("click", function(){

                jQuery(this).addClass("current").parent().parent().find("a").not(jQuery(this)).removeClass("current"); // wow!
                var cnt = -(pictWidth*z);
                container.find("ul").animate({ left: cnt}, settings.easeTime, settings.easeFunc);
                return false;
                   });
                }); 


                // next image via image click   14/01/2009
                jQuery("div#stripTransmitter" + j + " a").parent().parent().parent().prev().find("img").each(function(z) {
                jQuery(this).bind("click", function(){
                    var ui  =   jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().next().find("a");
                    if(z+1 < pictEls){
                        ui.eq(z+1).trigger("click");
                    }
                    else ui.eq(0).trigger("click");
                   });
                });

            jQuery("div#stripTransmitter" + j).css("width" , pictWidth);
            jQuery("div#stripTransmitter" + j + " a:first").addClass("current");
            if(settings.toolTip){
            container.next(".stripTransmitter ul").find("a").Tooltip({
                track: true,
                delay: 0,
                showURL: false,
                showBody: false
                });
            }
            });
        j++;
  });   
};
```

Comment: Do you find your code readable? Me not.

Comment: Hi Darin - Sorry about that! All fixed now :)

Comment: Thanks Natrium, that looks even better now!

Comment: The "alt" attribute is not for comments!!  The "alt" attribute is text to be show when the image cannot be loaded or when the rendering software doesn't do images (screen readers for blind people).  The "title" attribute is what should be used for flyover descriptive text.

Answer (score 1):

The first image has no caption because the caption displays only after `onclick`.
This can be fixed by inserting:

```
var altText = $(this).find("img").eq(0).attr("alt"); 
$("#caption").html(altText).fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as:

```
$("div").html( $("#myImg").attr("alt") );
```

**When** do you want this to happen?

Comment: Hi Mark! Thanks for your help! In terms of the above script, I'd be looking to display the caption when the image is "active" on screen!

Answer (score 0):

The image is activated (or brought into view) on screen by this line

```
container.find("ul").animate({ left: cnt}, settings.easeTime, settings.easeFunc);
```

you need to modify this line to:

```
container.find("ul").animate({ left: cnt}, settings.easeTime, settings.easeFunc, function(){
   // z is the index of the currently showing picture, 
   // it comes from the .each call above

   var altText = $(this).find("img").eq(z).attr("alt"); //get alt value

   // now insert the text from the alt value
   $("#id_of_your_text_display_div").html(altText);
});
```

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys!

I tweaked ekhaled's version of the script so that the caption was displayed underneath the first image in the series, as well as a simple fade effect for captions for any subsequent images - it's all working brilliantly now!

Thanks again :)

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery("div.svw").prepend("<img src='/template/theme/designdistillery/img/bg-portfolio-loading.gif' class='ldrgif' alt='loading...'/ >"); 
});
var j = 0;
var quantofamo = 0;
jQuery.fn.slideView = function(settings) {
        settings = jQuery.extend({
        easeFunc: "easeInOutExpo",
        easeTime: 750,
        toolTip: false
        }, settings);
        return this.each(function(){
            var container = jQuery(this);
            container.find("img.ldrgif").remove(); // Removes the preloader gif
            container.removeClass("svw").addClass("stripViewer");       
            var pictWidth = container.find("img").width();
            var pictHeight = container.find("img").height();
            var pictEls = container.find("li").size();
            var stripViewerWidth = pictWidth*pictEls;
            container.find("ul").css("width" , stripViewerWidth);   
            container.css("width" , pictWidth);
            container.css("height" , pictHeight);
            container.each(function(i) {
                var altTextstart = $(this).find("img").attr("alt");
                $("#caption").html(altTextstart);   
                jQuery(this).after("<div class='stripTransmitter' id='stripTransmitter" + (j) + "'><ul><\/ul><\/div>");
                jQuery(this).find("li").each(function(n) {
                    jQuery("div#stripTransmitter" + j + " ul").append("<li><a title='" + jQuery(this).find("img").attr("alt") + "' href='#'>"+(n+1)+"<\/a><\/li>");                                     
                });
                jQuery("div#stripTransmitter" + j + " a").each(function(z) {
                    jQuery(this).bind("click", function(){  
                        $("#caption").html(altTextstart).hide();    
                        jQuery(this).addClass("current").parent().parent().find("a").not(jQuery(this)).removeClass("current");
                        var cnt = -(pictWidth*z);
                        container.find("ul").animate({ left: cnt}, settings.easeTime, settings.easeFunc,function(){
                            // z is the index of the currently showing picture, 
                            // It comes from the .each call above
                            var altText = $(this).find("img").eq(z).attr("alt"); // Get alt value
                            // Now insert the text from the alt value
                            $("#caption").html(altText).fadeIn("slow");
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                }); 
                jQuery("div#stripTransmitter" + j + " a").parent().parent().parent().prev().find("img").each(function(z) {
                    jQuery(this).bind("click", function(){
                        var ui  =   jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().next().find("a");
                        if(z+1 < pictEls){
                            ui.eq(z+1).trigger("click");
                            }
                            else ui.eq(0).trigger("click");
                         });
                    });
            jQuery("div#stripTransmitter" + j).css("width" , pictWidth);
            jQuery("div#stripTransmitter" + j + " a:first").addClass("current");                        
            if(settings.toolTip){
                container.next(".stripTransmitter ul").find("a").Tooltip({
                    track: true,
                    delay: 0,
                    showURL: false,
                    showBody: false,
                    });
                }
            });
        j++;
    });
};
```

Comment: since you have used all the code I provided... it would make sense to mark mine as the answer :-)